Issue in sorting autotask rest api response
I'm facing an issue in sorting autotask API response.
I tried finding any specific order or keys in API response but did not find anything. There is nothing mentioned in the autotask API documentation. I'm stuck. Is there any way to do what I tried with created at -1 but it did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
